# Output in multiple parts of the page

Tags: javascript, ember.js

index.html:

```
<div id="section_a">
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    First value: {{input type="text" value=one}}<br>
    Second value: {{input type="text" value=two}}<br>
    Result: {{result}}
  </script>
</div>
<div id="section_b">    
  <!-- Display {{result}} here aswell -->
</div>
```

application.js

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  one: 0,
  two: 0,
  result: function() {
    return this.get('one') + this.get('two');
  }.property('one', 'two')
});
```

I have a section of a page where I have some Ember interactions - a user inputs some values and a calculated result is displayed.

I now want to have the calculated result displayed in another part of the page that is outside the defined template, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: I think what you are really asking is how can you access that computed property in a another controller or template context, right?

Comment: Yes I assume so, if that's the way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

You could bind that property to the application controller and then use it anywhere you want in the application. For example:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['index'],
  indexResult: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.index.result')
});
```

Now you can use it anywhere within the application you want. Just tell the outlet's controller to need the application controller, then call that property in the template. Like so:

```
App.FooController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  //...
});
```

In the `Foo` template:

```
{{controllers.application.indexResult}}
```

Or, if you are within the application scope you can just do:

```
{{indexResult}}
```

Comment: OK I've read the docs on `needs` now and the solution seems very logical, but I cannot get it to work. Could you please give an example how the template could look like when inserting `{{controllers.application.indexResult}}`?

Comment: @Numbers Did you update both the application controller and the index controller to need eachother? If you want to call on the application controller from within a template, you need to make sure that you know what controller you are using for the template. Then, make sure that controller needs the application controller. Make sense?

Comment: `needs` in both controllers made a whole lot of difference :) But last thing, how would an outlet be named/structured so I finally could output `{{indexResult}}` anywhere outside the defined template?

Comment: You don't need to worry about the names of things. That is one nice thing about this pattern. All you need to do is make sure that if an outlet uses `{{controllers.application.indexResult}}`, its controller has the application controller in the needs. If you want to use `{{indexResult}}` then you can specify that as a computed property in the outlet's controller. No point in doing that unless you are overriding how that value is computed.

Answer (score 0):

One simple and straight forward solution would be:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

<div id="section_a">
    First value: {{input type="text" value=one}}<br>
    Second value: {{input type="text" value=two}}<br>
    Result: {{result}}
</div>
<div id="section_b">    
  <!-- Display {{result}} here aswell -->
</div>

</script>
```

Comment: Yea of course, but there are other things in the page that complicates stuff. So my code is a simplification for the purpose of readility.

Comment: Do you have a template || controller for your "section_b", too?

Comment: No template yet. It's just another part of the document.

Comment: Then it's outside the scope of your ember app and you can not use embers data binding abilities.

Comment: No workaround? Create a new template or something else? (Sorry for putting these beginner questions...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57636/discussion-between-oliver-and-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up another outlet that can be used to display the "result". You can read more about using outlets in the Ember.js Guides at http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Comment: Could you elaborate how an implementation with the scenario in the question could look like? I have a very simple app, nothing is defined in the Router yet.