# Get Ember-generated value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ember.js, event-handling, handlebars.js

I'm successfully rendering dynamic data with Ember:

```
<div id="ember_generated">{{result}}</div>
```

I want to get this data on every change with jQuery. The following is the best I can think of, but it doesn't do much:

```
$("body").on("change", "#ember_generated", function() {

});
```

Comment: Why do you want to use jquery to watch the data changing?  Why not use Ember?

Comment: I've been trying in that end (http://stackoverflow.com/q/24853897/3205492), but the whole thing seems too complicated for the beginner stage that I'm at the moment. So I figured that a jQuery hack could solve this temporarily.

Comment: Are you very familiar with the router yet?

Comment: I'm getting the overall concept but for the simple app I have I haven't been needing to define anything in it. So it's only `App.Router.map(function() {});`

Comment: Are you aware that the location of the script tags in the page doesn't dictate where it's placed in the page? (They are just templates that can be used throughout your app), I'm asking this cause it kind of looked like in your previous question you were injecting a script tag (template) in one place, and hoping to inject another script tag (template) in another hoping one would update another.

Comment: Here's a pretty simple example of having nested routes, and sharing models between the routes, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/830/edit .  (Matthew already covered a bit about how to share a property between controllers).  It's fairly important to understand how the outlets and routes/resources work.

Comment: And here is the jsbin I sent you before: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zijofi/3/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is:

```
$('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', '#ember_generated', function () {

});
```

Comment: Genius! Spot on what I was asking for.