# Watch inserted element and it's programmatically updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, onchange

An element is inserted in DOM.

The element's value is updated continuously.

How do I use jQuery to watch for these updated values?

I have been trying with the following code, but it doesn't react on changes:

```
$("body").on("change", "#inserted_element", function() {

});
```

Comment: More explanation, your question is unclear

Comment: There is no native JS event raised when the DOM is modified. Under what event is the element updated? Could you not add some code to that logic to add an event yourself? eg `$el.text('foo').trigger('changed');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The element is created/inserted by Ember and I don't have the control over it. That's why I would like to watch the element with the tools jQuery/native javascript could provide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Ember-generated value with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855890/get-ember-generated-value-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

There is no default api available for that. As for the below

```
$("body").on("change", "#inserted_element", function() {

});
```

is the #inserted_element a input text/select? The onchange element occurs when the value of element is changed. If #inserted_element is a div then it wont work since the inner_html is changing and not the value. Even input label might work

The place where you update the #inserted_element value, you could call a trigger.

Comment: Changing the element from `div` to `input` and have the updated value at the `value` attribute made a whole lot of difference! Thank you very much my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at MutationObservers and use it : http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/